# Send MimeMessage with MimeMultipart ( attachment file + text ) and JBoss 6.3

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment in my java program.

But I'm facing a problem, I receive an empty mail (without any HTML tag) when I execute my code through the JBoss Server. And when I execute my code through JUnit test.

I receive the mail with the attachment and the body.

With the same input data, the same mail server, I face two different behavior.

When I don't use the function mail.setContent, I receive a mail with body in my 2 environment ( JBoss and JUnit test ).

So it seems my problem is linked to the setContent function, MimeMultipart type and JBoss execution.

I use :

- Java jdk1.7.0_79
- Maven 3.3.9
- JBoss EAP 6.3
- javax.mail version : 1.6.0

Here is my code to send mail with attachment :

```
    public void sendWithAttachment(ByteArrayOutputStream  attachmentByte, String filename) {


    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "myhost");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "myport");


    try {
        final Address[] reply = {new InternetAddress("foo@test.fr")};

        final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

        final MimeMessage mail = new MimeMessage(session);

        String recipient = "foo-recipient@test.fr";
        String body = "test";
        mail.setFrom(new InternetAddress("foo@test.fr","foo@test.fr"));
        mail.setSubject("subject");
        mail.setReplyTo(reply);
        MimeMultipart multipart = generateAttachment(attachmentByte,filename,body);
        mail.setContent(multipart);

        final Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect();

        mail.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(destinataire,destinataire));
        transport.sendMessage(mail, mail.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    } catch (final MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private MimeMultipart generateAttachment(ByteArrayOutputStream  attachmentByte, String filename, String body) throws MessagingException {
    MimeMultipart res = new MimeMultipart();
    byte[] poiBytes = attachmentByte.toByteArray();  

    DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(poiBytes, "application/octet-stream");
    BodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
    attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    BodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textBodyPart.setText(body);
    textBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    res.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
    res.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
    return res;
}
```

Have you some idea or clue to resolve my problem please?

Thank you

Comment: Check your server's logs for errors or warnings, and see if you get any more details when enabling debug logs on the `org.jboss.as.mail` and `javax.mail` packages.

Comment: No ERROR or WARN in the jboss log, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

I know its a minor thing but I noticed your port and host properties are set to the same.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "myhost");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "myport");
```

and they should be

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "myhost");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "myport");
```

I found this page, https://www.journaldev.com/2532/javamail-example-send-mail-in-java-smtp helpful when running a poc recently.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the error in the properties. It's a recopy error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
The problem comes from JBoss 6 javax library which was different than myApp javax library.
I modify the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file from my app with :

```
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api"/>
        <module name="javax.mail.api"/>
    </exclusions>
```

and I load all my external jar :

```
 <module name="modules.my.app" export="true" services="import"
            slot="${framework.versionSlot}">
            <imports>
                <include path="**" />
            </imports>
</module>
```

Now JBoss uses the good library and it works